# Git push -u origin master error wrong username or password

Tags: github, repository, git-push

I'm trying to do git push -u origin master but I'm getting error invalid username or password but I'm entering the correct username and password and I've tried over 10 time and have even typed in slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if:

- the URL is an HTTPS one (`git remote -v`)
- if you have [2FA in place](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa)

If both conditions are true, you might need to [create a personal access token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line), to be used in place of your account password.

Comment: Yes both of thoes where true and I created a access token and it worked, thank you!

Comment: @TheNamelessGuy Great, well done! Glad you made it work.